# Frequent SE Linux alert after upgrading systemd from rpm rebuild

Tags: systemd, selinux

This is the scenario.

I am using CentOS 8 and I have updated the systemd to a higher version (rebuild rpm from fedora 33).

Now I get frequent SE Linux alert. I am pretty sure its not a systemd bug, but just some settings I missed to update too.

The only way to fix is to issue the following command:

```bsh
sudo usearch ... && sudo semodule ...
```

What is the exact reason this is happening?

It was saying SE Linux is preventing access.

Why is SE Linux causing this issue and how to actually prevent getting this problem the next time I update systemd?

Comment: Well, what is the exact alert you're getting, and what are the exact commands you're using to "fix" it?

Comment: I am afraid its too many to write, there maybe about hundreds. So I believe its something that is not supposed to produce warning on stock systemd. I included the generic command to fix those, these are also suggested by selinux. The alert is about selinux preventing access to everything. See post :)